# Как получить пути к стандартным папкам пользователя (Рабочий стол, Загрузки и т.п.)?

Tags: python

Нужно получить пути к стандартным системным папкам пользователя, таким как:

- Домашняя папка
- Рабочий стол
- Загрузки
- Изображения
- Документы и т. п.

Как это можно сделать кроссплатформенно?

Comment: `path = os.path.expanduser(r'~\Downloads')`например

Comment: @Violet так делать нельзя, см. ответ

Comment: прошу прощения, был невнимателен. но "так делать нельзя" относится к конкретному случаю или это в принципе моветон?

Comment: @Violet «в принципе» не моветон, если достоверно известно, что папка обязана лежать строго по указанному пути. Но вот системные папки не обязаны, ОС предоставляет возможности для их перемещения куда-нибудь

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сразу нужно отметить, что подобные папки **можно переместить за пределы домашней папки пользователя**, так что наивные решения вроде `os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')` будут работать **некорректно** — не делайте так нигде кроме macOS.

В разных ОС есть свои правильные способы получения путей.

### Windows

В Windows для этого есть Win32 API метод [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath). Для его использования можно установить [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) (с помощью команды `pip install pywin32`) и использовать примерно так:

```py
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
path = shell.SHGetKnownFolderPath(shellcon.FOLDERID_Documents)
print(path)
# C:\Users\username\Documents
```

В первом аргументе нужно передать идентификатор нужной папки (одну из констант KNOWNFOLDERID). Полный список идентификаторов можно [почитать на MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid), здесь приведу наиболее интересные:

- `shellcon.FOLDERID_Profile` — папка пользователя (`C:\Users\username`);
- `shellcon.FOLDERID_Desktop` — рабочий стол (`C:\Users\username\Desktop`);
- `shellcon.FOLDERID_Documents` — документы (`C:\Users\username\Documents`);
- `shellcon.FOLDERID_Music` — музыка (`C:\Users\username\Music`);
- `shellcon.FOLDERID_Pictures` — изображения (`C:\Users\username\Pictures`);
- `shellcon.FOLDERID_Videos` — видео (`C:\Users\username\Videos`);
- `shellcon.FOLDERID_Downloads` — загрузки (`C:\Users\username\Downloads`);
- `shellcon.FOLDERID_RoamingAppData` и `shellcon.FOLDERID_LocalAppData` — `AppData\Roaming` и `AppData\Local` соответственно.

В Windows XP и более старых можно использовать устаревший метод [SHGetFolderPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw), но он имеет ограничения:

```py
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
path = shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_DESKTOP, None, 0)
print(path)
# C:\Users\username\Desktop
```

Второй параметр — идентификатор папки, путь к которой мы хотим получить. Полный список можно [почитать на MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/csidl), но через pywin32 работают не все.

### macOS

Если я правильно понимаю [документацию](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html), в macOS пути строго фиксированны. Так что всё, что нужно сделать, — это получить путь к домашнему каталогу и дописать к нему нужные подкаталоги.

Функция `os.path.expanduser` может сделать всю работу за нас: если в начале пути стоит тильда, она заменит его на путь к домашнему каталогу. Домашний каталог в macOS и Linux вычисляется так: если существует переменная окружения `HOME`, то берётся её значение, а если её нет, то считывается путь с помощью функции `getpwuid`.

```py
import os

# Просто домашний каталог — в macOS будет /Users/username
home_dir = os.path.expanduser("~")

path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")  # Рабочий стол
path = os.path.expanduser("~/Documents")  # Документы
path = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads")  # Загрузки
path = os.path.expanduser("~/Movies")  # Видео
path = os.path.expanduser("~/Music")  # Музыка
# Настройки приложений, местный аналог Application Data
path = os.path.expanduser("~/Library/Application Support")
```

Также это всё легко делается с помощью [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) — объекты `Path` более удобны в пользовании, чем обычные строки.

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path.home() / "Desktop"
path = Path.home() / "Documents"
path = Path.home() / "Downloads"
path = Path.home() / "Movies"
path = Path.home() / "Music"
path = Path.home() / "Library" / "Application Support"
```

### Linux, *BSD (XDG)

Unix-подобные ОС обычно опираются на стандарты [freedesktop.org](https://freedesktop.org/) (больше известны по аббревиатуре XDG) и хранят пути к стандартным папкам в файле `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` — получить интересующий путь в терминале можно командой [xdg-user-dir](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/) (это короткий bash-скрипт на несколько строк), например `xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD`.

Каждая строка в файле `user-dirs.dirs` имеет переменную в формате `XDG_xxx_DIR`, где `xxx` — тип каталога. Путь к каталогу должен или быть абсолютный (начинаться на `/`), или начинаться на `$HOME/` — другие форматы не допускаются.

К своему удивлению, я не обнаружил готового парсера этого файла для Python; впрочем, его нетрудно написать самостоятельно, используя библиотеку [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) (`pip install python-dotenv`, не забудьте добавить опцию `--user` если нужно):

```py
import os
from dotenv import dotenv_values

def get_user_dir(name: str) -> str:
    # Сперва получаем домашний каталог традиционным способом
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser("~")

    # Потом ищем путь к каталогу, в котором хранятся настройки
    config_dir = os.getenv("XDG_CONFIG_HOME") or os.path.join(home_dir, ".config")

    # Загружаем файл с описанием каталогов
    data = dotenv_values(os.path.join(config_dir, "user-dirs.dirs"))
    
    # Получаем путь из файла или генерируем его, если в файле нет нужного пути
    key = f"XDG_{name}_DIR"
    if key in data:
        path = data[key]
    elif key == "DESKTOP":
        path = os.path.join(home_dir, "Desktop")
    else:
        path = home_dir

    # Если путь начинается на $HOME, то нужно подставить туда домашний каталог
    if path.startswith("$HOME/"):
        path = os.path.join(home_dir, path[6:])

    return path
```

```py
print(get_user_dir("DOWNLOAD"))
# /home/username/Загрузки
```

В этом файле представлены следующие переменные (названия папок могут отличаться в зависимости от текущего языка системы):

- `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` — `/home/username/Рабочий стол`
- `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR` — `/home/username/Загрузки`
- `XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR` — `/home/username/Шаблоны`
- `XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR` — `/home/username/Общедоступные`
- `XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR` — `/home/username/Документы`
- `XDG_MUSIC_DIR` — `/home/username/Музыка`
- `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` — `/home/username/Изображения`
- `XDG_VIDEOS_DIR` — `/home/username/Видео`

Comment: А вот для macOS я Python-решения не нашёл :(

Comment: MacOS: а чем `str((Path.home() / "Desktop").resolve())` не подходит??

Comment: @MaxU я не уверен, что путь всегда будет гарантированно таким

Comment: я не нашел в сети как можно переименовать папку Desktop на MacOS. Все решения основаны на использовании "symbolic links", значит `(Path.home() / "Desktop").resolve()` - должен правильно отработать в данном случае...

Comment: @MaxU ну ладно, в [документации](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) возможности замены путей я не нашёл, обновил ответ. А вот симлинк на десктоп система постоянно норовит снести и создать вместо него пустой каталог, так что, похоже, симлинки официально не поддерживаются... В линуксе с симлинками тоже проблемы, кстати

Answer (score 0):

В линуксе ещё можно таким вариантом воспользоваться:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

user_dirs = {}

args = ['DESKTOP', 'DOWNLOAD', 'TEMPLATES', 'PUBLICSHARE', 'DOCUMENTS', 'MUSIC', 'PICTURES', 'VIDEOS']

for arg in args:
    r = subprocess.run(['xdg-user-dir', arg], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    user_dirs[arg.lower()] = r.stdout.decode('utf-8').rstrip()

for key in user_dirs:
    print(f'{key}: {user_dirs[key]}')
```

Вывод:

```
desktop: "/home/user/Рабочий стол"
download: "/home/user/Загрузки"
templates: "/home/user/Шаблоны"
publicshare: "/home/user/Общедоступные"
documents: "/home/user/Документы"
music: "/home/user/Музыка"
pictures: "/home/user/Изображения"
videos: "/home/user/Видео"
```