# Как узнать имя накопителя, на котором стоит ОС

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10

**Как узнать имя накопителя, на котором стоит ОС**, чтобы потом подставить его в путь, например:

```
OS_DISK = os.getCurrentOsDisk()
file = open(OS_DISK + "users/user_1/appdata/local/temp/tmp.txt")
file.write("Hello World!")
```

Посоветуйте как это можно узнать. Где-то читал что текущая директория обозначается `$`, так ли это?

Comment: В таком случае нужно уж идти дальше и принимать во внимание, что appdata может находиться вовсе не на системном диске

Comment: Ну хорошо, а если мне надо открыть какой-то файл из папки "Документы", при этом подставив название диска, то как реализовать это?

Comment: А «Документы» вообще не в appdata. Про выяснение расположения пользовательских папок я писал здесь: [Как получить пути к стандартным папкам пользователя (Рабочий стол, Загрузки и т.п.)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1236375)

Comment: В пути вижу упоминание временного каталога. Он хранится в переменной `%TMP%`, если что.

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае помогло `os.path.expanduser('~')`. Пример использования:

```
x = os.path.expanduser('~')
print(x)
```

Выводит:

```
C:\Users\KakaBik
```

Насколько я понял, работает это одинаково и на Linux, и на MacOS. Только пути будут разные

Comment: В вопросе одно, в комментариях другое, в ответе третье. Бардак какой-то... Ну и каталог пользователя может находиться не на системном диске

Comment: Нет, каталог пользователя не может быть перемещён. Он всегда будет только на том диске, где система. Могут быть перемещены только папки в каталоге например: "Рабочий стол", "Загрузки" и другие. Спасибо за ссылку на ваш ответ, очень информативно

Comment: Может-может, хотя делать это и не рекомендуется. Вот упоминание такого перемещения на сайте Microsoft есть, например https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/relocation-of-users-and-programdata-directories